# Click download button on webpage and save file in bash with shellnium

Tags: bash, selenium, download, click

On the webpage "https://www.raiplayradio.it/programmi/gr3/" I want to download the latest news show using bash. When doing it manually I would click the first "Podcast"-button and save the mp3 file.

I hoped to automate it using bash with shellnium. I tried the following methods without succes:

```
# Rai: version with css selector:
    local knop=$(find_element 'css selector' 'li.podcast')
    click $knop



# Rai: version with class name:
    local knop=$(find_element 'class name' 'podcast')
    click $knop
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a "accept cookies" element on the bottom of the page. You should first close it by something like

```sh
local knop=$(find_element 'css selector' 'button[data-context="YES"]')
click $knop
```

Even after that there is another element there overlapping the element you want to click.
I would suggest you to scroll the page up half page height.
I'm not sure about bash, while coding with Java, Python etc we normally use JavaScript for that. So please try this:

```js
jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight / 2)")
```

How you should be able to perform your original code

```sh
# Rai: version with css selector:
    local knop=$(find_element 'css selector' 'li.podcast')
    click $knop
```

Comment: The code for "closing something" gives an error: "parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 8
9793"

Comment: The scrolling code gives the following error: "/home/pw/Scripts/Test/Rai-Gr3-Dekunstgreep-Be: line 99: syntax error near unexpected token `"window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight / 2)"'